# How to check if android app user is connected to server

Tags: java, php, android, session, server

I am making an android application which communicates with my server every time the user logs in. I am trying to make it so that the server will know when a user is logged in or not (basically keeping track of their activity). However, if the device goes offline suddenly and doesn't have time to "logout" from the server, my server will never know that it is offline until the app requests the logout method. I am using baasbox for my backend. Can someone help me fix this? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: *"Can someone help me fix this?"* - Fix it how?

Comment: ok so how would i make it so that the server would know that the user is not active even if the device has not called the logout method

Comment: Do your want to check realtime about the access ?

Comment: you can use some sort of timestamp in your database that gets updated on regular intervals.  If the timestamp for a user is older than a few intervals, that user has logged off without an internet connection or they have dropped their connection.